# What precision is used by std::chrono::system_clock?

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, system-clock

Here's some code that I found:

```cpp
std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
```

This prints `1662563612364838407` for me; so it looks like this prints the number of nanoseconds since the UNIX epoch (1970-01-01).

But is this precision guaranteed? I didn't find any indication at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock that this value will always be in nanoseconds. Is it possible that this will return e.g. microseconds with another compiler, operating system or hardware?

Comment: it's unclear. `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` also doesn't have defined precision, because nothing can be counted faster than the system tick. For example on a small embedded MCU it can be microseconds

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not guaranteed. You can use the clocks `period` member alias to get tick period in seconds:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << std::chrono::system_clock::period::num << " / " << std::chrono::system_clock::period::den;
}
```

Possible output:

```
1 / 1000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that this will return e.g. microseconds with another compiler, operating system or hardware?

Yes, but you can always [`std::chrono::duration_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration_cast) it into a known duration unit. If you want it in seconds for example:

```cpp
auto dur = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(
               std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch());

std::cout << dur << '\n';
```

Possible output:

```
1662575635s
```

Pre C++20:

```cpp
std::cout << dur.count() << '\n';
```

```
1662575635
```

Note: Stay within the `chrono` domain until it's absolutely necessary to leave it (using `.count()` etc).